# SO - Annual survey - contractors

Tags: discussion, survey

What kind of information should be provided by contractors?

If I provide my services though my own company, am I supposed to provide answers for my company or my clients?

For example, should my client be in retail business how do I answer the question "How would you best describe the industry you currently work in?"` Retail or Consulting?

The same applies to "How many people work for your company?" - do I answer this from the point of view of my company or my client?

Comment: I would assume you should answer the questions in relation to your company's perspective, as its characteristics are globally applicable to your client base. If you answered from your client's perspective, then you'd have to submit one annual survey for each client (which is a huge time waster).

Comment: I moved this over from Meta Stack Exchange, although realistically I think this probably deserves additional discussion now that it's 4 years later. I'll ping folks internally on Monday to get this (back) on the radar.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you talk about a real company, than you're contracted by your own company.

Depending on whether you can speak for the company then or for yourself, you can answer this or that way.

> How would you best describe the industry you currently work in?

You should know that, I can not give any guidance.

> How many people work for your company?

Well that is *your* company right. Just name the number of employees your company has. It's not asking about one/all of your client(s) employees.

Answer (score 4):

I got the following email from Director of Marketing from Stack Exchange:

> As a rule of thumb, you should answer the questions based on the
>   company on your paystub - in this case your company the consulting
>   business. So, the industry would be consulting and the size of the
>   company would be how many people work for you.
>
> Sorry this wasn't clear.